# Change Image() object dimensions (width and height)

Tags: javascript, canvas, aspect-ratio

I am attempting to resize an image's dimensions, whilst retaining it's aspect ratio. This seems like a very simple task, but I cannot find a rellevent answer anywhere.. (relating to JavaScript's `Image()` object). I'm probably missing something very obvious. Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var img = new window.Image();
img.src = imageDataUrl;
img.onload = function(){
    if (img.width > 200){
        img.width = 200;
        img.height = (img.height*img.width)/img.width;
    }
    if (img.height > 200){
        img.height = 200;
        img.width = (img.width*img.height)/img.height;
    }
};
```

This is to proportionally resize an image before being drawn onto a canvas like so: `context.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);`.However it would appear I cannot directly change `Image()`dimensions, so how is it done? Thanks.

**Edit:** I haven't correctly solved the image [proportions](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/ratio4.htm) using cross-multiplication. @markE provides a neat method of obtaining the correct ratio. Below is my new (working) implementation:

```
var scale = Math.min((200/img.width),(200/img.height));
img.width = img.width*scale;
img.height = img.height*scale;
clearCanvas(); //clear canvas
context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
```

Comment: You should set the size of the image in arguments passed to [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). Also, in general, it's safer to set a load handler for an image first, then the src.

Comment: Can you provide greater detail for better testing? -- like the image reference and the HTML.

Comment: That is true, thank-you @Teemu However if I set those variables like so `context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);` or `context.drawImage(img,0,0,null,null);`, it still stretches or doesn't change the image dimensions. It would appear `Image()` doesn't have `.width` and `.height` variables?

Comment: What is the desired effect?  Anything larger than 200x200 will just be resized to 200x200 regardless of aspect ratio.  Are you trying to make it always fit in the canvas or always cover it?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I am trying to maintain an aspect ratio, whilst ensuring the image fits within the canvas.. Looking at my current code I can see what you mean - if the image's width and hieght is bigger than 200, then it will merely get set to 200. What do you suggest?

Comment: If canvas is bigger than image, use `Math.min( 200 / img.width, 200 / img.height, 1 )`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how to scale your image proportionally:

```
function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
    return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}
```

Usage:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/balloon.png";
function start(){

  canvas.width=100;
  canvas.height=100;

  var w=img.width;
  var h=img.height;

  // resize img to fit in the canvas 
  // You can alternately request img to fit into any specified width/height
  var sizer=scalePreserveAspectRatio(w,h,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h,0,0,w*sizer,h*sizer);

}

function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
  return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Original Balloon image resized to fit in 100x100 canvas</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Nice use of `Math.min()`.

Comment: If canvas is bigger than image, use `Math.min( maxW / imgW, maxH / imgH, 1 )`

Answer (score 5):

The image dimensions are set in the constructor

```
new Image(width, height)
// for proportionally consistent resizing use new Image(width, "auto")
```

or

```
the context.drawImage()
```

the arguments are as follows:

```
context.drawImage(image source, x-coordinate of upper left portion of image,
y-coordinate of upper left portion of image,image width,image height);
```

simply position the the image with the first two numeric coordinates and then manually adjust the size with the last two (width,height)

```
//ex.
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var img = new Image (200, "auto");
    img.src = "xxx.png";
context.drawImage(img,x,y,img.width,img.height);
```

Comment: Setting `auto` will fallback to `0`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-height